# What's the best way to reference files from a controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Currently because of multiple includes & requires I need to use the following code when referencing a file in my views:

```
require_once('../app/views/pages/home.php');
```

But I don't think this is a good idea, is there some way to make referencing files cleaner and reducing the risk of maintenance problems later on?

Comment: Are you using any mvc framework or building your own? If you're building your own the all approach is incorrect.

Comment: You could use a function to clean the code up. It depends really how you are styling your page.

Comment: Are you not using an [autoloader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)?

Comment: @AndréFerraz I am building my own, could you please explain why my approach is incorrect? Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to build my own MVC framework and I'm not that familiar with what's available so no I don't @RossKeddy

Comment: Well seems like your not using Models, Blocks/Views or Controllers at all. I'd say use already build examples to learn from it or study. There are very light weight MVC out there like slim framework or nano https://github.com/rwarasaurus/nano

Comment: @AndréFerraz Oh, I am using controllers, views and models. I don't have time to learn a framework atm so I need to make it work quickly, not sure if trying to make my own MVC is the way but I'm too deep to stop now :( Thanks tho

Comment: @Heraclitus can you share the code? Do you have a repository?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is on a web server, I usually use something based on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, so you'd have something like:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/views/pages/home.php');
```

If it's not on a web server or something that supplies that `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, if you have a config file that is automatically read by every script in your project, you could define a constant with the absolute path to your code root, and reference that similarly.  (If that's the case and you need more specifics, I can provide an example.)